# The two Strings don't update, keep returning "?"

Tags: java, eclipse

This is just a class file of my whole project. I've checked everyother class and I found that this was the culprit. It's supposed to take in the city and state that was parsed in another class(so you're left with city=Dallas and state=TX for example) but when those parameter are passed through, they don't update the private String state and private String city.

I keep getting ?,? as the output from the toString method

```
    public class Address 
{
private String city;
private String state;

public Address()
    {
    city="?";
    state="?";
    }

public String getCity()
    {
    return city;
    }

public String getState()
    {
    return state;
    }

public void setState(String s)
    {
    //System.out.println(s);
    state=s;
    //System.out.println(state);
    }

public void setCity(String c)
    {
    city=c;
    }

public String toString()
    {
    String cityState=city+","+state;
    return cityState;
    }

}
```

Tester Class

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Assignment4
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    { // local variables, can be accessed anywhere from the main method
  char input1;
  String inputInfo = new String();
  String line = new String(), line2;
  //instantiate a Bank array
  Bank[] accounts = new Bank[10];
  Bank bank1 = null;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int index = 0;
  // print the menu
   printMenu();
   do  // will ask for user input
    {
     System.out.println("What action would you like to perform?");
     line = scan.nextLine().trim();
     input1 = line.charAt(0);
     input1 = Character.toUpperCase(input1);

     if (line.length() == 1)
      {// matches one of the case statements
       switch (input1)
        {
         case 'A':   //Add Bank
           System.out.print("Please enter the bank information:\n");
           inputInfo = scan.nextLine();
           bank1 = BankParser.bankParser(inputInfo);
           accounts[index] = bank1;
           index++;
           break;
         case 'B':   //Display banks
           for (int i=0; i< index; i++)
                    System.out.print(accounts[i].toString());
           break;
         case 'Q':   //Quit
           break;
         case '?':   //Display Menu
           printMenu();
           break;
         default:
           System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
           break;
        }
      }
     else
      {
       System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
      }
    } while (input1 != 'Q' || line.length() != 1);
  }


  /** The method printMenu displays the menu to a user**/
  public static void printMenu()
  {
   System.out.print("Choice\t\tAction\n" +
                    "------\t\t------\n" +
                    "A\t\tAdd Bank\n" +
                    "B\t\tDisplay Banks\n" +
                    "Q\t\tQuit\n" +
                    "?\t\tDisplay Help\n\n");
  }
 }
```

Bank.java class

```
    public class Bank 
    {
    Address Address=new Address();
    private String bankName;
    private String bankID;
    private Address bankAddress= new Address();

    public Bank()
{
bankName="?";
bankID="?";

}

    public String getBankName()
{
return bankName;
}

    public String getBankID()
{
return bankID;
}

    public Address getBankAddress()
{
return bankAddress;
}

    public void setBankName(String bName)
{
bankName=bName;
}

    public void setBankID(String bID)
{
bankID=bID;
}

    public void setBankAddress(String city, String state)
{
Address.setCity(city);
Address.setState(state);
}

    public String toString()
{
String bankInfo="\nBank Name:\t\t"+bankName+"\nBank ID: \t\t"+bankID+"\nBank        address:\t\t"+bankAddress+"\n\n";
return bankInfo;
}
    }
```

BankParser.Java class

```
    public class BankParser 
    {
public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse)
{
    Bank bank=new Bank();
    String delims="[/]+";
    String[] primaryParse=lineToParse.split(delims);
    bank.setBankName(primaryParse[0]);
    bank.setBankID(primaryParse[1]);
    String[] secondaryParse=primaryParse[2].split("[,]");
    //String city=secondaryParse[0];
    //String state=secondaryParse[1];
    bank.setBankAddress(secondaryParse[0], secondaryParse[1]);
    //System.out.println(secondaryParse[1]);
    return bank;
}


    }
```

Comment: The problem is not with the code you've posted above. Please show the code where you test this class. Are you ***sure*** that you're calling the `setCity(...)` and `setState(...)` methods ***before*** printing out the object?

Comment: This code is OK, your problem is outside of this class.

Comment: The tester class was provided by my professor, he said we couldn't modify it.

Comment: We're not asking you to modify it, just show it to us.

Comment: I'm adding the tester class to the question, I'll add the two other classes as well that i'm using

Comment: You realize that the tester class doesn't use your Address class at all, right? Also, maybe your classmate could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487760/why-arent-my-variables-changing-after-my-methods-tell-them-to-java#comment32433945_21487760

Comment: I just added all 3 of the classes and the tester, I should have realized to do that in the first place

Comment: You have 2 Adresse instance fields. You're using `Address` (the field) to set its value, but you're returning `bankAddress` in the `getBankAddress()` method.

Comment: `Address Address = new Address();` That's not going to get confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setBankAddress(String city, String state)
{
    Address.setCity(city);
    Address.setState(state);
}
```

Here is your problem, you did likely want to do

```
public void setBankAddress(String city, String state)
{
    bankAddress.setCity(city);
    bankAddress.setState(state);
}
```

instead.

Comment: Then kindly accept the answer to close the question as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. Test the following to convince yourself:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("Albany");
    address.setState("NY");
    System.out.println(address.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two Address objects,  one named Address and one named bankAddress. You are setting the city and state values on the Address object but returning the bankAddress object. You only need to have one Address object that you set the values on and return.